# Reduce delay on mouse hovering over user names

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

Can the reputation popup delay be reduced a bit when hovering over a user?

[image]

I remember it once was faster, was the delay added intentionally?

Answer (score 9):

This is not something the site can implement, because the reputation tooltip you see is *rendered entirely by the browser*.

The HTML element you are hovering over has a [`title="<reputation>"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title). How quickly a tooltip is rendered is a browser feature.

Comment: It's nowhere near as slow for me in Chrome.

Comment: Same in Firefox.

Comment: @Cerbrus weird, it is for me (on MacOS). Exactly as demonstrated.